# How can I make a 2x2 grid with perfect margins using flexbox?

Tags: css

I am something new in css and I am trying to have a `2x2 grid` and inside each container I want to put a .`card` with perfect `margins` (the same distance for each `card` in any direction). I would like to achieve something like the image and avoid scrolling in any direction.

[image]

how can i do it?

thanks

```css
.col-6{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap is taking 15px padding for both Left and Right,but you can modify it by giving additional padding, and for  avoid scrolling in any direction you have to write some code below i attached. Let me know you have any question.

```css
.col-6{
border:1px solid red;
}

.my-vh{
  height: 100vh;
}

.my-card{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="my-vh">
      <div class="row h-100">
         <div class="col-6 p-3">
            <div class="card my-card p-5">
               text1
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 p-3">
            <div class="card my-card p-5">
               text2
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 p-3">
            <div class="card my-card p-5">
               text3
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 p-3">
            <div class="card my-card p-5">
               text4
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for `.row` it have a margin-left & margin-right -15px. so put m-0 for row and add padding in col.

```css
.wrapper{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column vh-100">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 m-0">
    <div class="col-6 h-100 p-1">
        <div class="card h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 h-100 p-1">
        <div class="card h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 m-0">
      <div class="col-6 h-100 p-1">
          <div class="card h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              text3
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 h-100 p-1">
          <div class="card h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              text4
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! but I need it to cover 100% of the height and width of the window. Something like in my picture.

Comment: I have edited the code. check that. I had changed the bootstrap version so we can use flex-grow-* classes.

Comment: No custom classes used except a wrapper to add the red border.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in below way.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style type="text/css">

.main_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.card_section {
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
</style>

<div class="main_container h-100">
    <div class="card_section">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_section">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_section">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_section">
        <div class="card m-1 ">
            text4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
.col-6{
border:1px solid red;
}

HTML
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row h-100 m-0">
    <div class="col-6 p-1">
        <div class="card">
            text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-1">
        <div class="card">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-1">
        <div class="card">
            text3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-1">
        <div class="card">
            text4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```